# Cannot POST /uploadfile flask react

Tags: reactjs, flask

I wanna import a file and save it to a folder but when I click to upload show me  Cannot POST /uploadfile 
I don't know why !! 
this is my code, thanks in advance for help !

** code flask **

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('uploadfile')
@app.route('/uploadfile', methods=["POST", "GET"])
@cross_origin(support_credentials=True,origin=[ 'http://localhost','http://0.0.0.0'], headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
@flask_security.login_required
def uploadfile():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        # print('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file'].read()
    if file.filename == '':
        # print('No file selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file :
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # print('File successfully uploaded')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect(request.url)
```

** code react  **

```
return (  
    <DashboardLayout>
      <form action="/uploadfile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file"  required></input>
      <input type = "submit"/>

      </form>
      </DashboardLayout>

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.read()` from `file = request.files['file'].read()` and try.